# Identifying if only the diagonal is non-zero

Tags: r

Let's say I have a matrix with all 0's with the exception of the diagonal.

```
m <- matrix(ncol=3,nrow=3)
m[,1] <- c(1,0,0)
m[,2] <- c(0,1,0)
m[,3] <- c(0,0,1)
```

What logical check could I use to test if the upper and lower triangle of the matrix are zero?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
all(m[lower.tri(m)] == 0, m[upper.tri(m)] == 0)
```

Comment: or `all(m[!diag(nrow(m))] == 0)`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slightly shorter alternative to @GregaKešpret's excellent solution:

```
m <- diag(11:13)
m

all(m[!diag(nrow(m))] == 0) # TRUE

m[1,2] = 0.01
all(m[!diag(nrow(m))] == 0) # FALSE
```

The `diag` function has two major modes: Give it a vector as in `diag(11:13)` and it puts it on the diagonal. Or give it a number as in `diag(3)` and it creates a identity matrix of that size. Then I extract all the non-diagonal elements and compare them to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check for:

```
sum(m) == sum(diag(m))
```

Comment: `matrix(c(1,-1, 1,-1), byrow=TRUE, nrow=2)`

Comment: OP: `Let's say I have a matrix with all 0's with the exception of the diagonal.`

Comment: `sum(abs(m)) == sum(diag(abs(m)))`